# What to call tests that check that output has not changed?

Tags: testing, terminology

This is a question about terminology, not about method.

Our application consists of physical simulations. Results have been validated in various ways, but we have no oracle that guarantees correctness. Nonetheless, to improve and extend our software we need tests that ensure that at least we did not break things that worked satisfactorily so far.

Therefore we wrote tests that run a simulation and check whether the output, within a certain noise level, agrees with reference data that have been generated by running the very same simulation using the old, validated version of our software. **How to call such tests?**

A name that comes to mind is "regression test", but according to Wikipedia and other sources, this term is applied to whatever tests that have accumulated in a test suite; so it is not specific enough for our kind of tests.

Comment: from [wikipedia Regression_testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing) : "Regression testing ... is re-running functional and non-functional tests to ensure that previously developed and tested software still performs after a change". Can you tell us where you get this from "according to Wikipedia and other sources, this term is applied to whatever tests that have accumulated in a test suite" ?

Comment: "where you get this from"? isn't the logic the other way round?

Comment: the first "..." is cited from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing

Comment: This I know. I was rather concerned about the unclear wording "where you get this from" of yours. I still think that you mean it the other round: How do I get my "... whatever tests that have accumulated ..." from Wikipedia's "... tests to ensure that previously ... tested software still performs ..."? Is that your question?

Comment: you said "but according to Wikipedia and other sources, this term is applied to whatever tests that have accumulated in a test suite; " My qestion: do you have a link for this?

Comment: You have given the right link above. I did not quote verbatim, otherwise I would have used quotation marks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Characterization test** is a term for this, introduced by Michael Feathers in *Working Effectively With Legacy Code*.

You're not testing whether the output is correct or not, and in many applications there is no precise definition of correctness. You're just using the test to guard against unintended changes to the behaviour of the subject under test.

Comment: I confirm, he introduces the term in Chapter 13 of his book (2005 edition).

Comment: Had Feathers come here, maybe we could have suggested him a better term. Why not snapshot? Too late, his term has found some acceptance and already has a decent Wikipedia article, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterization_test. So I will go for this. Thank you, @bdsl, and thanks to everybody for your helpful contributions.

Comment: I would be quite confused if someone called the test the OP is describing a characterization test. The goal of a characterization test is to create a testing scaffolding around untested code to make it possible to change it safely by documenting how it currently behaves. This does not seem to be what the OP is using this test for.

Comment: I commented at one point that I prefer this term over snapshot test. However, snapshot tests and characterization tests serve different purposes. In the book, "legacy code" is defined as code that doesn't have tests. A characterization test helps a developer understand what the legacy code does and refactor with confidence.

Comment: @VincentSavard: We need these tests to safely change our code. Sorry if that was not clear in my original posting.

Comment: @JoachimW Let me rephrase: characterization testing is performed on untested code to document how it currently behaves. By explicitly comparing the current output with a previous one, you are _not_ performing characterization testing, you are defining expectations.

Comment: "In the natural flow of development, tests that *specify* become tests that *preserve* [Feathers, p. 185].

Comment: @JoachimW So you are _not_ testing against a previous version of the output, just what the output should be, is that correct? That is a very important distinction from your original question which you should definitely edit in. Which just makes your test... a test. Possibly a unit test, or an integration test, or maybe an end-to-end test, depending on how you test it.

Comment: We are testing current output against output from previous versions of our software. That old output is stored as reference data.

Comment: @JoachimW Then, just like I was saying, this is not a characterization test. We're just making circles now, so if that's what you want to call your tests, it is up to you, but note that it is _not_ what the community considers to be a characterization test.

Comment: Sorry, Vincent, I have the Feathers book at hands, and I am pretty sure he describes exactly our way of testing: Write a characterization test that describes the actual behavior of the code. Then change the code, and rerun the characterization test.

Comment: I added a couple of paragraphs to my answer explaining the difference between snapshot and characterization. At this point I'm not sure into which category your simulation testing falls, but if we can reach a consensus on the definitions I'll be happy.

Comment: Still in reply to @VincentSavard, here two more quotes: "We are trying to put in a mechanism to find bugs later, bugs that show up as differences from the system's current behavior" [p. 188]. And even clearer: "characterisation tests ... verify that particular behaviors are present. From their presence, we can infer that refactorings we have done ... have preserved behavior" [p. 194].

Comment: @JoachimW A characterization test is not intended to document the correct behaviour, only the current behaviour, which may not changed at any point due to being unspecified. The implementation _is_ the specification, in that situation. My interpretation of your question is that it was not the case, that your simulation _is_ specified and that you merely wanted to test it against a historically accurate output of a previous calculation. If my interpretation is wrong, then sure, call it a characterization test.

Comment: The question is not whether there exists a specification, but whether there are tests that can ensure the specification is met. If there were satisfactory tests, no need to resort to characterization tests. Since there aren't, our old software version, validated in various informal ways, is the best proxy for specified behavior we can have.

Comment: @JoachimW "Since there aren't [...]" This is the key piece of information missing from your question. From this comment thread, then yes (at last! you might say :) ), I agree with you that you are performing characterization testing.

Comment: @VincentSavard: I expanded the question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @JoachimW It is to me! I upvoted your question and this answer.

Answer (score 9):

You're overthinking this. You're testing whether the output of the algorithm has regressed since the previous version of the code, so it's a regression test.

Comment: This is the fallback solution: We'd have a regression test suite that contains some regression tests in the narrower sense, and some other tests. Let's wait whether someone can help out with a more specific term.

Comment: @JoachimW Still overthinking. It's a test that finds regressions, so call it a regression test. If somebody else says "that's not how we did regression tests at my company!" you can say "so?"

Comment: @JoachimW Should we also not both call them a "test" because they're different? No, because they're both tests, just different kinds of tests. Should we call one a "regression" test but not the other? **No**, because they're both regression tests, just of different kinds of regression. Call it a "noise regression test" (or anything else that takes your fancy) if you need to disambiguate between the two, but this is much too niche to expect to find a standardized name that is conventionalized across the entire field of software engineering.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to tackle your question from the standpoint of terminology rather than testing method, even though terminology and testing method can be intertwined. As you'll see further in my answer, this is all a matter of perspective.

The term "regression test" is very broad. While specific definitions vary, the essence of a regression test is to guard against problems appearing as the code base evolves. A regression test is not a methodology, or specific kind of test. The fact is, a unit test verifying a function returns false given certain input is also a regression test. So is an integration test that verifies an e-mail gets sent.

Basically, a "regression test" is something that should keep working as the code base is changed. This does not imply that a newly written test verifying existing behavior is somehow *not* a regression test. The time at which the test is written does not make it a regression test. The *behavior* the test verifies is what makes it a regression test. If that behavior is pre-existing, then a newly written test would simply be called "adding regression test coverage."

> In a scientific application, we have plenty of tests that run a simulation and check whether the output, within a certain noise level, agrees with reference data that have been generated by running the very same simulation under an earlier version of our software.

This is just a rewording of the colloquial definition for regression test. It doesn't matter if you wrote a test this morning that verifies something that's been in the system for 10 years. It is still a regression test.

If we add "test methodology" to your question, then what you are talking about is *still a regression test,* but could also be another kind of test at the same time. Being that this is a scientific application, I assume the output to be quite complex, but still in the realm of raw data. In that case, Patrick McElhaney's answer also applies. Not only are you writing regression tests, but those tests could also be classified as snapshot tests. Arguably they could be called functional tests as well.

This happens frequently with testing terminology. There is no central authority defining these terms. How you classify a test largely depends on the context of the conversation. As a result, a single test can fall into multiple categories.